# Perl - passing user inputted cgi form data to perl program to be then put into mysql database

Tags: html, mysql, forms, perl

I've tried searching forums for a solution, however most of the answers were either too difficult to understand. SO I'm in the process of making a website for a small community, and currently we have our database and html design layout, but I'm getting snagged on how to push my Perl CGI form into another Perl program to then alter my database.

Here is the Perl controller that alters the database tables (and it works):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
#!/usr/bin/perl -wT

# DBI is the standard database interface for Perl
# DBD is the Perl module that we use to connect to the <a href=http://mysql.com/>MySQL</a> database
use DBI;
use DBD::mysql;

use warnings;

#----------------------------------------------------------------------
# open the accessDB file to retrieve the database name, host name, user name and password
open(ACCESS_INFO, "accessDB.txt") || die "Can't access login credentials";


# assign the values in the accessDB file to the variables
my $database = <ACCESS_INFO>;
my $host = <ACCESS_INFO>;
my $userid = <ACCESS_INFO>;
my $passwd = <ACCESS_INFO>;
my $tablename = "Article";

# the chomp() function will remove any newline character from the end of a string
chomp ($database, $host, $userid, $passwd);

# close the accessDB file
close(ACCESS_INFO);
#----------------------------------------------------------------------

# invoke the ConnectToMySQL sub-routine to make the database connection
$connection = ConnectToMySql($database);

if ($tablename == "Article"){
    $connection = InsertArticle($database);
}

elsif ($tablename == "Category"){
    $connection = InsertCategory($database);

}
elsif ($tablename == "Comment"){
    $connection = InsertComment($database);

}
elsif ($tablename == "User"){
    $connection = InsertUser($database);

}
else {
    print "No such table found. Contact website administrator.\n"

}
sub InsertArticle{

$query = "insert into $tablename (Id, CategoryId, UserId, Title, Content) values(?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";

$statement = $connection->prepare($query);


$statement->execute('undef', '1', '1029', 'Dota2>League', 'textfromarticle');
}
sub InsertCategory{

$query = "insert into $tablename (Id, CategoryId, UserId, Title, Content) values(?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";

$statement = $connection->prepare($query);


$statement->execute('undef', '1', '1029', 'Dota2>League', 'textfromarticle');
}
sub InsertComment{

$query = "insert into $tablename (Id, CategoryId, UserId, Title, Content) values(?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";

$statement = $connection->prepare($query);


$statement->execute('undef', '1', '1029', 'Dota2>League', 'textfromarticle');
}
sub InsertUser{

$query = "insert into $tablename (Id, CategoryId, UserId, Title, Content) values(?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";

$statement = $connection->prepare($query);


$statement->execute('undef', '1', '1029', 'Dota2>League', 'textfromarticle');
}

exit;

#--- start sub-routine ------------------------------------------------
sub ConnectToMySql {
#----------------------------------------------------------------------

my ($db) = @_;

# assign the values to your connection variable
my $connectionInfo="dbi:mysql:$db;$host";

# make connection to database
my $l_connection = DBI->connect($connectionInfo,$userid,$passwd);

# the value of this connection is returned by the sub-routine
return $l_connection;

}

#--- end sub-routine --------------------------------------------------
```

In the future, I'll define the other tables in my database through global variables that depend on what button the user presses on the correct webpage. As in, if they're viewing a list of articles, an option at the top would be "submit an article". And from there, the form CGI would be sent to them that they can fill out.

And here is the CGI that makes the form that would be submitted to the above controller script to alter the table:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
#!/usr/bin/perl -wT
    use strict;
    use warnings;
    use CGI;
    use CGI::Carp qw(fatalsToBrowser); #remove this in production

 my $q = new CGI;
 print $q->header;                                                  #Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1
 print $q->start_html(
    -title => 'submit an Article',                                  #page name
    -style => {'src' => '/dmrwebsite/dmrwebsite/userinterface'},    #link to style sheet
    );
print $q->start_form(
    -name => 'submitting an Article',
    -method => 'POST',
    enctype => &CGI::URL_ENCODED,
    -onsubmit => 'return true',
    -action => '/dmrwebsite/dmrwebsite/controller.addtotable.pl',
);
print $q-.textfield(
    -name => 'title',
    -value => 'default value',
    -required,
    -size => 20,
    -maxlength =>50,
);
print $q->textarea(
    -name => 'content',
    -value => 'default value',
    -required,
    -maxlength => 1000,
    -cols => 60,
);
print $q->textarea(
    -name => 'url',
    -value => 'default value',
    maxlength => 100,
    cols =>60,
);
print $q-checkbox(
    -name => 'humancheck',
    -checked => 1,
    -value => 'two',
    -label => 'The number two',
);
print $q-submit(
    -name => 'submit_Article',
    -value => 'submit Article',
    -onsumbit => 'javascript: validate_form()',
);
if ($q->param()) {
    submit_form($q);
} else {
    print "Please check your form for inaccuracies.";
}
sub submit_form($){
    my ($q) = @_;


}
print $q->end_form; #ends the form html
print $q->end_html; #end the html document
```

So basically what I'm stuck at is understand how to send the form data to the perl script in which I can then define the table data in `my $tablename = "Article";` and `$statement->execute('undef', '1', '1029', 'Dota2>League', 'textfromarticle');`.

Also, I don't have a javascript program to send to the parameter `-onsubmit => javaapplication(),`. Is that needed? Can I substitute my own Perl program to check the user inputted fields? And how would I call this function? IN the same file or can it just be in the parent directory like /website/perlchecker.pl?

Any help would be greatly appreciated as I'm only a couple days into using Perl let alone CGI and html. Got a couple people helping me on the front end of the website though.

Thanks,
-Ori

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So many suggestions...

Firstly, your DB insertion program seems to just insert fixed data, so I'm not sure how you think that it works. Also, the `if ($tablename == "Article")` (and similar) line doesn't do what you want it to. You need to use `eq` instead of `==`.

To answer the question that you asked - you need to change your database program so that it accepts input (probably command line arguments) containing the data that you want inserted into the database. You would then add to your CGI program a line that calls this program (probably using `system()`) passing it the data from the CGI parameters on the command line.

The code would look something like this:

```
my $title   = $q->param('title');
my $content = $q->param('title');
# ... other params ...
system('db_script.pl', 'Article', $title, $content, ...)';
```

But please don't do that. That's a terrible idea.

Instead, I highly recommend that you re-write your database manipulation program as a module. That way, you can load the module into any program that needs to talk to the database and access the database by calling functions rather than by calling an external program. If it was down to me, then I'd definitely use [DBIx::Class](https://metacpan.org/pod/DBIx::Class) to produce this library - but I realise that might well be seen as rather advanced.

Then there's the elephant in the room. You're still using CGI to write your web interface. The CGI module has been removed from the latest version of Perl as it is no longer considered best practice for writing web applications. I recommend looking at [CGI::Alternatives](https://metacpan.org/pod/CGI::Alternatives) to find out about other, more modern, tools.

But if you're determined to carry on writing your program as a CGI program, then at the very least, please don't use the HTML generation functions. We've known that including your HTML in your program source code is a terrible idea for at least fifteen years. There's no reason to still be doing it in 2015. You should really be using some kind of templating engine to separate your HTML from your Perl code. I recommend the [Template Toolkit](https://metacpan.org/pod/Template).

I'm not sure where you are learning these techniques from, but your source seems to be a good ten years behind accepted best practice.

Comment: My database insertion program works as in it hits the database and inserts that fixed data. Some my thinking is that if I can make global variables that are pulled from some html form, then I can insert them into that insertion program to alter the database.

Comment: So, if i rewrite the database module, how would I go about using it for form submission from a webpage? The only reason I went to use CGI was because any sort of google search for html form input to perl program came up witht hat as the solution. 

So, as a newbie to web development everyone is telling me that php sucks compared to Perl, but I can't seem to find any answers on things such as DBIx::Class or how to connect an html form to a perl script to insert the information into my database.

Comment: So starting from there, since I apparently am 10 years behind, the basic idea is, I have a database of things such as articles, users, content, etc. I want an ability for users to submit these things through a common form that can then be displayed on the website.

Comment: Your database insertion program works by accident. It only seems to work as it will always insert data into the first table listed in your "if/elsif'..." block. Try setting `$tablename` to a value other than "Article" and see which of your `InsertFoo()` subroutines gets called.

Comment: Okay so I changed the `my $tablename = "Category";` and the if/elsif to using `eq` instead of `==` : `elsif ($tablename eq "Category"){$connection = InsertCategory($database);}`

Using that recommendation it went to the correct subroutine.

Comment: Yep. That was the problem. Using `==`, Perl does a numeric comparison and under Perl's data conversion rules `"Article" == "Category"` (for example) is true - as both non-numeric strings get converted to 0.

Comment: Oh okay, and should I be using Dancer2 instead of CGI? I looked into it, but it seems really complex to just get into. Is there any sort of beginner tutorials to get into it?

Comment: I agree that finding good reference material about modern Perl using Google is hard. Google seems rather swamped by the huge amounts of dodgy Perl material that was put on the web in the last millennium. You might want to read [Beginning Perl](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9781118013847.do) or take a close look at the tutorials at [Perl Maven](http://perlmaven.com/). I'm also supposed to be writing a book about modern Perl web development - but it's slow progress :-/

Comment: There are some Dancer tutorials at [Perl Maven](http://perlmaven.com/dancer). It's also worth taking a look through the [Dancer Advent Calendar](http://advent.perldancer.org/2014) articles.

Comment: Okay, thanks, I'll close this question now as you have answered it!

Comment: You can also go and talk to the Dancer people in #dancer on irc.perl.org. They are generally very friendly and helpful. The Dancer2::Manual is pretty good to get started.